# Test user's paypal details

Tags: php, paypal

I am developing an LMS in which I have the following scenario.

A teacher will create an account now different students can see the subject offered by the teacher and lets suppose one of the student buys a subscription for a subject offered by the teacher.

Now when the student will pay, the amount will directly go into admin's account(not the teacher).

Now the admin can release the payment whenever he wants from the backend, in this case using paypal I need to have all the information like

```
API_USERNAME
API_PASSWORD
API_SIGNATURE
API_ENDPOINT
```

Now the logic I thought of so far is I will get all the information of teacher while registering i.e given above, and I will also have the admin information of paypal, when the admin will release payment, I will use the details from admin and make a payment in background and transfer it to the teacher's account!

now what if the teacher made a mistake in one of the above information? i will no doubt receive an error on the backend that I can display but what if I can test the user's above given information while registering that will confirm that there will be no issue in transferring money.

so my question is can test user's paypal information somehow? or is there any better logic to my scenario? this is a big project for me and I would appreciate any sort of help!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using paypal's new [marketplaces api](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplaces/pp4mp/) for this type of scenario. I believe it's still in early access so you would have to request access from paypal.

With this solution, you are able to incorporate an "on-boarding" process in which when a teacher registers, you also have them grant you access to accept payments on their behalf.

When a student pays for a course, you would then complete the transaction using the teachers paypal account and set the status to "DELAYED". A delayed order status tells paypal to hold the funds before transferring them to the teachers account. To disburse the funds you would then be able to login to your admin interface and make a call to the api which tells paypal to release the funds to the teacher.

If paypal is not a prerequisite and you are only looking to accept payments via credit card, you can also accomplish this scenario using [stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/connect), which in my experience is a much more straight forward process and is readily available without the need to request permission.

With stripe you have a similar onboarding process when a teacher registers. If they do not have an existing stripe account they are prompted to create one, then allow your application access to accept payments on their behalf.

When a student pays for a course, you would save their payment method(information is stored on stripe and you are issued a reference token) and alert the admin that a purchase is pending approval. The admin would then approve or deny the purchase. It is at this stage when the students payment method would be used to create the charge.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was perfectly what i was looking for a little explanation! Keep up the good work

Comment: one more thing are there any codes available? through which i can have an idea of how to use paypal market places api?

Comment: Being early access there's not a lot of examples floating around yet. PayPal does do a decent job of providing some usable documentation though: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplaces/connected/integration-guide/ There are also links to the rest api on that page. Remember, none of this will be available until your account has been granted access to the api from paypal.